# Firebase on ios is slow in retrieving new chat message data

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, chat

Built a basic chat feature in my app with the help of Firebase. Each time i open the chat group view, there is a huge delay in retrieving the new chat message data.

Below is the query i use for fetching new chat data.

```
fb = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/messages/groupId/];
[fb keepSynced:NO];
[[fb queryLimitedToLast:20] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSMutableDictionary * newMessage = snapshot.value;
    [newMessage setValue:snapshot.key forKey:MSG_MESSAGEID];
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(firebaseCallbackWithData: eventType:)]) {
        [self.delegate firebaseCallbackWithData:newMessage eventType:ReceiveNewMessage];
    }
}];
```

[Screenshot of Message data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6dUM.png)

Comment: Your code works correctly if the *if (self.delegate)* section is commented out. Also, MSG_MESSAGEID wasn't defined in your question so in testing I substituted a string. I would suspect that code section may be responsible for the delay so try commenting it out and see if there's a difference.

Comment: No the issue is not due to extra piece of code. If a user receives messages in his chat group when he is offline, the new messages (messages that were sent went he was offline) takes a few seconds to be retrieved, when he opens the chat view. the snapshot with the old data comes instantaneously (as firebase saves data the retrieved data locally). But the messages that was sent when user was offline takes times and comes as a new snapshot after a delay.

Comment: You should probably update the question what that additional information as the question doesn't mention the user being offline and that could affect the answer.